# Mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs

Tags: c++, mysql, xcode

I love Apple and Xcode, but I won't deny this is the sort of "Apple stuff" that drives me crazy! :)

I code C++ as many people solve crossword puzzles. I am not a professional, nor do I intend to ever be one! :)

I am playing with MySQL and its C++/Connector. I've downloaded the DMG file from the MySQL site and now I wanted to write C++ code. When I link `libmysqlcppconn.dylib` with my program, I get the very annoying error below:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libSQL.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.22/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.22/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs
```

So, I know XCODE has found the MySQL library (after a lot of Search Path updates), but now it says the MySQL library doesn't belong to "my team"!

How can I fix this?

(I've tried codesign, outside XCODE, but no bliss)

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_disable-library-validation?language=objc) help?